# Error during connecting firebase to project

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I try to connect Firebase to my project.
*Tools -> Firebase*
When I click "connect to firebase" I see error Couldn't find registrable Android clients in project.

Any idea? Thannks